# Count number of common column names among all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, metadata

Is there any way to compare every table with each other in a database, listing the number of common columns between each tables? I prefer using join over subquery and `information_schema.columns` over `sys.columns`, if possible.

For example, if I have 4 tables, I'd expect output like this:

```
list1        list2        commonColumns  
-----       --------     --------------------
table1     table2         1
table1     table3         2
table1     table4         0
table2     table1         1
table2     table3         5
table2     table4         2
table3     table1         3 
table3     table2         0
table3     table4         1
table4     table1         2
table4     table2         3
table4     table3         0
```

Comment: Why would you prefer [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` over `sys.columns`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4381789/2503214

Comment: And did you [read my link](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)? If you're sticking with SQL Server, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` will do you no favors, and it will become increasingly less reliable as you move to new versions and new features are added...

Comment: Note also that the answer there compared `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to `sysobjects` (an old, backward-compatible system table from SQL Server 2000), not to `sys.objects` (a newer catalog view).

Comment: may be you are right but sys.columns only gives me column names. how do I get the table name it belongs to?

Comment: `sys.columns` contains `object_id` - this can be joined to `sys.tables` or `sys.objects` or, like in my answer, you can get the table name without a join, using the `OBJECT_NAME()` function instead. However note that some metadata functions  block, [and this behavior will not be fixed](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432497/metadata-functions-should-follow-same-isolation-semantics-as-metadata-queries). So on production systems during normal operations, it is sometimes better to have a messier join.

Comment: Your sample output doesn't make sense, by the way. Why is table1 / table3 listed, as well as table3 / table1? Why do they have a different number of common columns? Won't they have the same number of column columns regardless of which one you look at first? And even if they matched, why bother listing x+y and y+x? I think your sample output rowcount should be `(n-1)!/2` (where `n` is the number of tables in the database), not `(n-1)!`. My answer only bothers to list each combination once, with the lower name (alphabetically) on the left.

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: What was wrong with the `sql` tag?

Comment: @Andriy Added the `sql-server` tag. `sql` tag: I thought the question is more about SQL Server than SQL.

Comment: @Yasir: The question is about writing a SQL query for SQL Server, so it's equally about both (IMHO). (I can see that you've already put the tag back, so I'm merely saying that to help you to overcome your doubts, in case there still are any.)

Comment: @Aaron-I agree, I must confess I didn't think it through when making an example. sorry abt tht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want schema name along with table name, and here is a way to get the information from the proper catalog views instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` ([more on why here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)).

```
;WITH c AS 
(
  SELECT 
    t = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])) 
      + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])), 
    name
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0
)
SELECT 
   list1 = c1.t, 
   list2 = c2.t, 
   commonColumns = COUNT(CASE WHEN c1.name = c2.name THEN 1 END)
 FROM c AS c1
 INNER JOIN c AS c2
 ON c1.t < c2.t
 GROUP BY c1.t, c2.t
 ORDER BY c1.t, c2.t;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/461bf/1)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. thank you Aaron. looking at your blog very informational.